# Different results in Sublime and Jupyter

Tags: python, arrays, sublimetext3

When i run this command in Jupyter and execute it, it shows it as an **array of list** (even though i didn't write print statement)

[image]

while, when i run same command in Sublime Text and press ctrl+b, it just shows that the execution is finished and won't show result like above. Is there any way to show same result in Sublime as well?

[image]

Comment: Use `print` to see output in sublime

Comment: It’s not output, it’s the value of the last expression in the code.

Comment: Is there any way to print value of last expression in Sublime (like jupyter does)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- to get an output is standard code (`*.py` file): use `print()`.
- to get an output in a notebook ('*.ipynb' file), you can use `print()` or simply the last variable is displayed. This is very convenient.

some editors (like `vscode`, not sure if the same for sublime) allow for a hybrid. So the user can create cells inside a `*.py` file like this:

```
#%% <--- creates a "jupyter like" cell..

a = 10
a
```

which looks like this:
[image]

This has the convenience that the coder can run parts of the code (the cells) with out having to run other parts of the code (that might be longer routines).

also note that in the picture example, the user can replace `a` for `print(a)` and both would return 10.

Comment: if i just print that statement in Sublime, it returns output of: [0 2 4 6 8]. But the real value stored in shell is supposed to be "array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])". It's an array of list, not just an array. So, is there any way to print the value stored in shell or the value of expression in Sublime?

Comment: if you do `type(np.arange(0,10,2, dtype='int'))` then you will explicitly see the type which is a `numpy.ndarray`... a list would be `x = [2, 4, 6, 8]`. numpy arrays and lists have similarities, but are inherently different...